# Error in installing pandas using pip on python 3.4, ubuntu 15.10

Tags: python, pandas, pip

Trying to install pandas with pip (python3.4) on ubuntu 15.10, I am getting this error. The numpy version is 1.12 (latest). I have installed pandas on ubuntu and windows but never faced this kind of problem.

```
Downloading/unpacking pandas
  Downloading pandas-0.19.2.tar.gz (9.2MB): 9.2MB downloaded
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-build-5lvucprd/pandas/setup.py) egg_info for package pandas

    package init file 'pandas/io/tests/sas/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    warning: no files found matching 'README.rst'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/build'
    warning: no directories found matching 'examples'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*~' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '#*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.git*' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '.DS_Store' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.png' found anywhere in distribution
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): python-dateutil>=2 in /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): pytz>=2011k in /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from pandas)
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): numpy>=1.7.0 in /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages (from pandas)
Installing collected packages: pandas
  Running setup.py install for pandas
    package init file 'pandas/io/tests/sas/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    package init file 'pandas/io/tests/sas/__init__.py' not found (or not a regular file)
    UPDATING build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pandas/_version.py
    set build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pandas/_version.py to '0.19.2'
    building 'pandas.lib' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Ipandas/src/klib -Ipandas/src -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c pandas/lib.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/pandas/lib.o -Wno-unused-function
    In file included from /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1788:0,
                     from /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                     from /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                     from pandas/lib.c:274:
    /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
     #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
      ^
    pandas/lib.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_6pandas_3lib_slice_get_indices_ex’:
    pandas/lib.c:28309:36: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘PySlice_GetIndicesEx’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
       __pyx_t_4 = PySlice_GetIndicesEx(((PySliceObject *)__pyx_v_slc), __pyx_v_objlen, (&__pyx_v_start), (&__pyx_v_stop), (&__pyx_v_step), (&__pyx_v_length)); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_4 == -1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 1723, __pyx_L1_error)
                                        ^
    In file included from /usr/include/python3.4m/Python.h:97:0,
                     from pandas/lib.c:4:
    /usr/include/python3.4m/sliceobject.h:43:17: note: expected ‘PyObject * {aka struct _object *}’ but argument is of type ‘PySliceObject * {aka struct <anonymous> *}’
     PyAPI_FUNC(int) PySlice_GetIndicesEx(PyObject *r, Py_ssize_t length,
                     ^
    pandas/lib.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_6pandas_3lib_slice_len’:
    pandas/lib.c:28532:36: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘PySlice_GetIndicesEx’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
       __pyx_t_4 = PySlice_GetIndicesEx(((PySliceObject *)__pyx_v_slc), __pyx_v_objlen, (&__pyx_v_start), (&__pyx_v_stop), (&__pyx_v_step), (&__pyx_v_length)); if (unlikely(__pyx_t_4 == -1)) __PYX_ERR(0, 1747, __pyx_L1_error)
                                        ^
    In file included from /usr/include/python3.4m/Python.h:97:0,
                     from pandas/lib.c:4:
    /usr/include/python3.4m/sliceobject.h:43:17: note: expected ‘PyObject * {aka struct _object *}’ but argument is of type ‘PySliceObject * {aka struct <anonymous> *}’
     PyAPI_FUNC(int) PySlice_GetIndicesEx(PyObject *r, Py_ssize_t length,
                     ^
    pandas/lib.c: In function ‘__pyx_pw_6pandas_3lib_65maybe_booleans_to_slice’:
    pandas/lib.c:13402:15: warning: ‘__pyx_v_end’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
         __pyx_t_6 = PyInt_FromSsize_t(__pyx_v_end); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_6)) __PYX_ERR(0, 767, __pyx_L1_error)
                   ^
    pandas/lib.c:13064:14: note: ‘__pyx_v_end’ was declared here
       Py_ssize_t __pyx_v_end;
                  ^
    pandas/lib.c:13400:15: warning: ‘__pyx_v_start’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
         __pyx_t_7 = PyInt_FromSsize_t(__pyx_v_start); if (unlikely(!__pyx_t_7)) __PYX_ERR(0, 767, __pyx_L1_error)
                   ^
    pandas/lib.c:13063:14: note: ‘__pyx_v_start’ was declared here
       Py_ssize_t __pyx_v_start;
                  ^
    pandas/lib.c: In function ‘__pyx_gb_6pandas_3lib_118generator’:
    pandas/lib.c:27176:38: warning: ‘__pyx_t_22’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
               __pyx_cur_scope->__pyx_t_8 = __pyx_t_22;
                                          ^
    pandas/lib.c:27173:38: warning: ‘__pyx_t_10’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
               __pyx_cur_scope->__pyx_t_4 = __pyx_t_10;
                                          ^
    pandas/lib.c:27170:38: warning: ‘__pyx_t_5’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
               __pyx_cur_scope->__pyx_t_3 = __pyx_t_5;
                                          ^
    pandas/lib.c:27175:38: warning: ‘__pyx_t_14’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
               __pyx_cur_scope->__pyx_t_7 = __pyx_t_14;
                                          ^
    pandas/lib.c:27174:38: warning: ‘__pyx_t_11’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
               __pyx_cur_scope->__pyx_t_6 = __pyx_t_11;
                                          ^
    pandas/lib.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_6pandas_3lib_183maybe_convert_objects.isra.211’:
    pandas/lib.c:1548:73: warning: ‘__pyx_pybuffernd_itimedeltas.diminfo[0].strides’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     #define __Pyx_BufPtrStrided1d(type, buf, i0, s0) (type)((char*)buf + i0 * s0)
                                                                             ^
    pandas/lib.c:54734:21: note: ‘__pyx_pybuffernd_itimedeltas.diminfo[0].strides’ was declared here
       __Pyx_LocalBuf_ND __pyx_pybuffernd_itimedeltas;
                         ^
    pandas/lib.c:54734:21: warning: ‘__pyx_pybuffernd_itimedeltas.diminfo[0].shape’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
    pandas/lib.c:1548:73: warning: ‘__pyx_pybuffernd_idatetimes.diminfo[0].strides’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
     #define __Pyx_BufPtrStrided1d(type, buf, i0, s0) (type)((char*)buf + i0 * s0)
                                                                             ^
    pandas/lib.c:54730:21: note: ‘__pyx_pybuffernd_idatetimes.diminfo[0].strides’ was declared here
       __Pyx_LocalBuf_ND __pyx_pybuffernd_idatetimes;
                         ^
    pandas/lib.c:54730:21: warning: ‘__pyx_pybuffernd_idatetimes.diminfo[0].shape’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/pandas/lib.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pandas/lib.cpython-34m.so
    building 'pandas._window' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Ipandas/src/klib -Ipandas/src -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c pandas/window.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/pandas/window.o -Wno-unused-function
    In file included from /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1788:0,
                     from /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                     from /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                     from pandas/window.c:274:
    /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
     #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
      ^
    pandas/window.c: In function ‘__pyx_pf_6pandas_7_window_26roll_window.isra.92’:
    pandas/window.c:34909:21: warning: ‘__pyx_pybuffernd_tot_wgt.diminfo[0].strides’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
       __Pyx_LocalBuf_ND __pyx_pybuffernd_tot_wgt;
                         ^
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/pandas/window.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pandas/_window.cpython-34m.so
    building 'pandas.io.sas.saslib' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Ipandas/src/klib -Ipandas/src -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c pandas/io/sas/saslib.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/pandas/io/sas/saslib.o -Wno-unused-function
    In file included from /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1788:0,
                     from /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                     from /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                     from pandas/io/sas/saslib.c:274:
    /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
     #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
      ^
    pandas/io/sas/saslib.c: In function ‘__pyx_f_6pandas_2io_3sas_6saslib_rdc_decompress’:
    pandas/io/sas/saslib.c:3619:65: warning: ‘__pyx_v_ctrl_bits’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
         __pyx_t_8 = (((__pyx_v_ctrl_bits & __pyx_v_ctrl_mask) == 0) != 0);
                                                                     ^
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/pandas/io/sas/saslib.o -o build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.4/pandas/io/sas/saslib.cpython-34m.so
    building 'pandas._period' extension
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Ipandas/src/klib -Ipandas/src -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c pandas/src/period.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/pandas/src/period.o -Wno-unused-function
    In file included from /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1788:0,
                     from /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                     from /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                     from pandas/src/period.c:275:
    /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
     #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
      ^
    In file included from pandas/src/period.c:277:0:
    pandas/src/datetime_helper.h:7:0: warning: "PyInt_AS_LONG" redefined
     #define PyInt_AS_LONG PyLong_AsLong
     ^
    pandas/src/period.c:163:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
       #define PyInt_AS_LONG                PyLong_AS_LONG
     ^
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Ipandas/src/klib -Ipandas/src -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c pandas/src/datetime/np_datetime.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/pandas/src/datetime/np_datetime.o -Wno-unused-function
    In file included from /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1788:0,
                     from /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                     from /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                     from pandas/src/datetime/np_datetime.c:18:
    /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
     #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
      ^
    In file included from pandas/src/datetime/np_datetime.c:10:0:
    /usr/include/python3.4m/datetime.h:191:25: warning: ‘PyDateTimeAPI’ defined but not used [-Wunused-variable]
     static PyDateTime_CAPI *PyDateTimeAPI = NULL;
                             ^
    x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -pthread -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fPIC -Ipandas/src/klib -Ipandas/src -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -I/home/sp/webapps/myenv/include/python3.4m -c pandas/src/datetime/np_datetime_strings.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/pandas/src/datetime/np_datetime_strings.o -Wno-unused-function
    In file included from /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1788:0,
                     from /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:18,
                     from /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                     from pandas/src/datetime/np_datetime_strings.c:17:
    /home/sp/webapps/myenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:15:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " "#defining NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
     #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it by " \
      ^
```

Comment: did you install with sudo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You always need the python-dev package to compile Python C extensions such as the ones in Pandas. When you install Python from source, they're installed along, but not with the Ubuntu package.

From `pip install --help`:

```
-U, --upgrade    Upgrade all packages to the newest available version
```

Pip Upgrade All Python Packages :

```
pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e' | cut -d = -f 1  | xargs pip install -U
```

Comment: on Ubuntu I had to go with the following formating: pip freeze --local | grep -v '^\-e'| cut -d " " -f 1 | xargs pip install -U